# Here SDK Crash any tip why?

Tags: here-api

With the Here SDK Navigate for Flutter. I'm seing this crash and no clue why it happens, I'm not using venues. Any tip?

Here's what I see in crashlytics

```
    libsyXstem_kernel.dylib
    __pthread_kill + 8
    libsystem_pthread.dylib
    pthread_kill + 268
    libsystem_c.dylib
    abort + 168
    libsystem_malloc.dylib
    _malloc_put + 550
    libsystem_malloc.dylib
    malloc_report + 64
    libsystem_malloc.dylib
    free + 300
    arrow_right 6
    heresdk
    here_sdk_sdk_venue_threading_VenueThreads_get_type_id
    libdispatch.dylib
    _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    libdispatch.dylib
   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 680
    libdispatch.dylib
   _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
    libsystem_pthread.dylib
   _pthread_wqthread + 228
    libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Comment: This crash needs to be symbolicated. It is not necessarily related to venues. Please contact the HERE team to symbolicate the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below hellomap example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/core.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/core.engine.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/core.errors.dart';
import 'package:here_sdk/mapview.dart';

void main() async {
  // Usually, you need to initialize the HERE SDK only once during the lifetime of an application.
  _initializeHERESDK();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

void _initializeHERESDK() async {
  // Needs to be called before accessing SDKOptions to load necessary libraries.
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);

  // Set your credentials for the HERE SDK.
  String accessKeyId = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID";
  String accessKeySecret = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET";
  SDKOptions sdkOptions = SDKOptions.withAccessKeySecret(accessKeyId, accessKeySecret);

  try {
    await SDKNativeEngine.makeSharedInstance(sdkOptions);
  } on InstantiationException {
    throw Exception("Failed to initialize the HERE SDK.");
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'HERE SDK for Flutter - Hello Map!',
      home: HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(HereMapController hereMapController) {
    hereMapController.mapScene.loadSceneForMapScheme(MapScheme.normalDay, (MapError? error) {
      if (error != null) {
        print('Map scene not loaded. MapError: ${error.toString()}');
        return;
      }

      const double distanceToEarthInMeters = 8000;
      MapMeasure mapMeasureZoom = MapMeasure(MapMeasureKind.distance, distanceToEarthInMeters);
      hereMapController.camera.lookAtPointWithMeasure(GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915), mapMeasureZoom);
    });
  }
}
```

For complete example  please check below link.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/hello_map_app